# RestSharp doesn't UTF-8 Encode the Request

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, utf-8, restsharp

I'm trying to POST a request with one lonely parameter, as such:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://www.fluff.com");
var request = new RestRequest("whatever", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("param", "Оксана");
client.Execute(request);
```

This results in the following request, notice the bunch of encoded question marks:

```
POST http://www.fluff.com/whatever HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml
User-Agent: RestSharp/105.0.1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: www.fluff.com
Content-Length: 24
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

param=%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F
```

Imagine the sadness when the receiver gets those question marks..

How do I make RestSharp properly encode the body as UTF-8, or how do I send the request in a RestSharp friendly way so that she doesn't garble the data?

Comment: Have you considered using HttpClient instead of RestSharp? [PostAsJsonAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944521) makes this about as easy as it gets.

Answer (score 2):

Christer, that's standard encoding for `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which uses ISO-8859-1 as a default.  If you specifically want to tell the server to expect UTF-8, you can add `; charset=UTF-8` at the end `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded ; charset=UTF-8`.  But then it's your responsibility to make sure the data you post is really encoded in UTF-8.

Or if you want to do it in "application/json", you can set the content type in this way (I got this from http://itanex.blogspot.com/2012/02/restsharp-and-advanced-post-requests.html):

```
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.Parameters.Clear();
request.AddParameter("application/json", strJSONContent, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

You could also use `multipart/form-data`: `<form action="YOUR_ACTION_NAME_HERE" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: "How do I make RestSharp properly encode the body as UTF-8, or how do I send the request in a RestSharp friendly way so that she doesn't garble the data?"

How do I set up RestSharp so that "Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8". RestSharp overrides my attempts to set the Content-type.

Does this make my question clearer?

Regards

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're saying, but I'm quite sure RestSharp (library for RESTful calls) is able to do this for me. I have written these types of libraries myself that handles this, and in our current project we have another library that handles this automatically, but since RestSharp is so lightweight and nifty I want to use it. The problem I'm facing now is that RestSharp doesn't allow me to just set the content type by specifying the header. It overrides my attempts to set it.

Comment: I think I found something else.  You may also have to specify the encoding in the AddParameter call:  `request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded ; charset=UTF-8", paramName, paramValue);`

Comment: See the updated answer with the code that I got from http://itanex.blogspot.com/2012/02/restsharp-and-advanced-post-requests.html.  This might be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I cleaned up various comments and simplified the answer.  In my original answer, I was not fully grasping your question.  I think the answer is now closer to what you were looking for.

Comment: If you want JSON, you can just use `request.AddJsonBody()`.

Comment: The main issue that using addParameter fails when making a POST and PUT is that RESTSharp sets the encoding to be form-urlencoded, by design since the author actually wants it that way. My technique was the solution to get around that issue. Does the method you suggest make the proper headers for POSTing json?